# How to resolve "Type of expression in ambiguous without more context"?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

```
let attributedString  =  NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!
```

Compiler error: "Type of expression in ambiguous without more context"
How could it be solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

required `[String : AnyObject]`format required by attributedOptions parameter

```
do {
        let encodedData = yourEncodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
        ]
        let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
       // self.init(attributedString.string)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Unhandled error: \(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift 2.0+, the error parameter should be dropped from the call. The compiler was misleading for me.

So instead of:

```
let attributedString  =  NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, 
     options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)
```

Use:

```
let attributedString  =  NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, 
     options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
```